# Structured types is empty

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I am passing 2 Data Tables (Structured types) **@tblParent** and **@tblChild** as input parameter to my stored procedure,

```
paramList.Add(DbSqlManager.CreateParameter("@tblParent", ParameterDirection.Input, alertsDataDt));
paramList.Add(DbSqlManager.CreateParameter("@tblChild", ParameterDirection.Input, alertsPointDataDt));
```

1. @tblParent has always minimum 1 record
2. @tblChild may have no records

While passing @tblChild with NO records, I am getting below obvious error,

**"There are not enough fields in the Structured type.  Structured types must have at least one field."**

**Question is,** Is there any way to handle this with no records in @tblChild??

Comment: Check your `DataTable`, it doesn;t seems to have any `Column` too, completely empty structure, that's why this error, as its not able to map with the Table Values Parameter Schema

Comment: correct, the question is can we skip this either in C# or Sql. I think NO

Comment: Make that parameter Optional in the Sql, then its not mandatory for you to provide it and you can always check while executing Sql what is the binded value

Comment: how to make DataTable variable as optional

Comment: Not `DataTable in C#`, but `Sql Server procedure`, where you are accepting the same as TVP

Comment: could you please some code/text

Answer (score 0):

The DataTable you are passing must at least have structure. Make sure alertsPointDataDt has the table structure. You can validate and pass null instead, like below:

```cs
paramList.Add(
    DbSqlManager.CreateParameter(
        "@tblChild",
        ParameterDirection.Input,
        alertsPointDataDt.Rows.Count > 0 ? alertsPointDataDt : null));
```

Comment: Please review your code as it will probably won't compile! `alertsPointDataDt.Rows.Count > 0 ? >> alertsPointDataDt: << null`